# Appending lists in SML

Tags: list, append, sml

I'm trying to add an int list list with another int list list using the append function, but I can't get it to work the way I want.

Say that I want to append `[[1,2,3,4,5]]` with `[6,7]` so that I get `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]`.

Here's my attempt: `[1,2,3,4,5]::[]@[6,7]::[]`, but it just gives me the list I want to append as a list of its own instead of the two lists combined into one, like this: `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7]]`.

How can I re-write the operation to make it return `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too unspecific. You are dealing with nested lists. Do you want to append the second list to *every* inner list of the nested list, or only the *first* one? Your example doesn't tell.

For the former:

```
fun appendAll xss ys = List.map (fn xs => xs @ ys) xss
```

For the latter:

```
fun appendHd [] ys = raise Empty
  | appendHd (xs::xss) ys = (xs @ ys)::xss
```

However, both of these should rarely be needed, and I somehow feel that you are trying to solve the wrong problem if you end up there.

Comment: Sorry, only the first one in this case. And you're right, I re-wrote my code and it now works the way it was intended to do. Thank you for making me realize!